# pygtk: how to manually emit signal

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have an `gtk.Entry()` object, and I would like to manually emit the `focus-out-event`. What is the second parameter that I need to pass to the `emit` method?

```
In [10]: d.emit('focus-out-event')
TypeError: 1 parameters needed for signal focus-out-event; 0 given

In [11]: d.emit('focus-out-event', d)
TypeError: could not convert type gtk.Entry to GdkEvent required for parameter 0
```

Comment: Why you want to emit `focus-out-event` ? and when (or where)? is it inside another event's handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a [`gtk.gdk.Event`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gdkevent.html) as the second parameter.

Here's how you create one: (disclaimer, I didn't test this)

```
event = gtk.gdk.Event(gtk.gdk.FOCUS_CHANGE)
event.window = entry.get_window()  # the gtk.gdk.Window of the widget
event.send_event = True  # this means you sent the event explicitly
event.in_ = False  # False for focus out, True for focus in
```

You can look up the different types of event and what parameters they require on the page I linked to above.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the error message says :-). But where do I get such an object from? Do I create it myself? With what attributes? Does it depend on the signal that I want to emit?

Comment: The event object is for the benefit of the handlers. You are supposed to create it when you emit the signal. If your handler doesn't use it, you might try just passing an empty object. But perhaps you can't assume that yours is the only handler. See my edit to the answer.